# How to show a label together with startAdornment in Multiple Select in Material UI?

Tags: material-ui, multiple-select

I am using the Select with the multiple prop. The component works fine, and the InputLabel renders the  renders the following:

[image]

However, when I add an icon at the beginning via the startAdornment prop, the InputLabel is moved above the input field.

[image]

Do you know how to show the label next do the icon when no values are selected?

The code is:

```
 <FormControl className={classes.formControl} fullWidth variant="outlined" size="medium">
    <InputLabel name={name} color="secondary" variant="outlined" htmlFor={id} id={id} className={classes.label}>{label}</InputLabel>
    <Select
      name={name}
      labelId={id}
      id={id}
      multiple
      autoWidth
      startAdornment={icon}
      color="secondary"
      value={selectedValues}
      onChange={handleChange}
      renderValue={selectedOptions => (
        <div className={classes.tags}>
          {selectedOptions.map(option => (
            <Chip key={option.value} label={option.label} size="small" className={classes.chipStyle} />
          ))}
        </div>
      )}

    >
      {options.map(option => (

        <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option}>
          <Checkbox checked={logicHere} color="primary" />
          <ListItemText primary={option.label} />
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Select>
  </FormControl>
```

Comment: Side node: the desired behaviour is defined by the [material design itself](https://material.io/components/menus/#exposed-dropdown-menu) - see "Outlined dropdown menu with a leading icon". So, either I do not understand how to use the component properly, or it's a bug

Comment: Did you wrap `icon` in an `InputAdornment`? In their [demo of text fields](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/), they have added an `InputAdornment` component around it

Comment: Yes, I tried 

   `startAdornment={
          <InputAdornment position="start">
            {icon}
          </InputAdornment>
        }`

and still the same

Comment: Its a known bug. The issue for it is here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13898

Answer (score -1):

Did you try ?

```
<Select 
InputProps={{
    startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">Kg</InputAdornment>,
}} />
```